# Alias the phone number of an incoming sms

Tags: android, sms, alias, sms-gateway, android-mms

I would like to know how some apps can send SMS to my Android and alias the sender phone number. Such as Twitter:

[image: Twitter]

Though I don't have it in my contacts, nor can I see the actual number it was sent from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is called 'Alphanumeric Sender ID' it is a service which is supplied by numerous companies such as "twilio" and "Plivo".

you can find extra information on how to create an account and use the API in here:

- https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/what-is-alphanumeric-sender-id-and-how-do-i-get-started
- https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/send-an-sms-with-alphanumeric-sender-id/